# Fabricjs - Rendering multiple canvases in one document

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I'm having a problem dynamically creating and setting canvas backgrounds.
I want the user to be able to annotate the images with text and shapes, thats why I am doing stuff this way.

I would like to know **why** is this code producing such output

**The idea**

1. Send a get request to an endpoint which returns json data containing
   image urls.
2. Convert that data into a javascript array.
3. Dynamically create fabric js canvases based on the length of above
   array.
4. Set the canvas backgrounds to the images using their urls. (i.e each canvas will have a different background taken from the url)

**The problem**

Only the last canvas has a background image.

**code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
      }
    </style>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="fabric.js"></script>
    <!--new start-->
    <script>
      //procedurally load images from a given source
      //endpoint with image links
      var end_point = "http://localhost:8080/endpoint.php";
      var settings = {
        url: "http://localhost:8080/endpoint.php",
        method: "GET",
      };
      //get the images array from end point
      $.ajax(settings).done(function (images_json) {
        var images = JSON.parse(images_json);
        //procedurally create farbric.js canvas for each image element in the html document and set their background as the corresponding image.
        //for each item in the images array, create a fabric.js canvas with its background set as the image itself
        var canvas_array = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
          //console.log(images[i]);
          //create canvas and then make it a fabric canvas
          document.body.innerHTML += `<canvas 
          id=${[i]} 
          width="1000" 
          height="200"
          style="border-style: solid;">
          </canvas>`;
          //canvases stored in canvas_array
          canvas_array[i] = new fabric.Canvas(`${[i]}`);
          console.log(canvas_array[i]);
          //set canvas background as the image
          canvas_array[i].setBackgroundImage(
            `${images[i]}`,
            canvas_array[i].renderAll.bind(canvas_array[i]),
            {
              backgroundImageOpacity: 1,
              backgroundImageStretch: false,
            }
          );
        }
      });
    </script>
    <!--new end-->
  </body>
</html>
```

**result**

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nPT2.png)

**note**
The code is generating correct number of canvases. However the background image does not seem to work

Desired result would have 10 canvases with different backgrounds corresponding to the image urls.

I'm new to fabric.js, this may be a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using remote source was a strict requirement. I tried several stuff and this finally worked.

**code**

```html
//c global variable
var n_can_arr = [];
var f_can_arr = [];
var img_arr = [];

//c procedurally load images from a given source
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/endpoint.php",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json", //c added data type
  success: function (res) {
    for (var index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
      //c create canvas
      var setHtml = `<canvas
        id=${index} 
        width="1000"
        height="800"
        style="border-style: solid;">
        </canvas>`;
      document.body.innerHTML += setHtml;
      //c update canvas and image arrays
      n_can_arr.push(index);
      img_arr.push(res[index]);
    }
    //c call image set after the loop is over
    $(document).trigger("images_set");
  },
});

//c on image_set called
$(document).bind("images_set", () => {
  //c for each element of normal canvas array, create a fabric js canvas and set its background
  for (var i = 0; i < n_can_arr.length; i++) {
    create_canvas(i);
  }
  //c for each element of fabric canvas array, apply the extend canvas function
  extend_canvas();
});

function create_canvas(i) {
  //c create fabric js canvases with normal canvas id from canvas arrray
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(`${i}`);
  f_can_arr.push(canvas);

  //c set canvas background using image array
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(img_arr[i], canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    backgroundImageOpacity: 1,
    backgroundImageStretch: false,
  });
}

function extend_canvas() {
  f_can_arr.forEach((canvas) => {
    var origX, origY, isDown, mode_rect, mode_uline, mode_free, pointer;

    //c setting keypress listener
    $(window).on("keypress", (e) => {
      console.log(e.key);
      //c drawing rectangles
      if (e.key == 1) {
        var rect;
        console.log("Box");
        isDown = true;
        mode_free = false;
        mode_uline = false;
        mode_rect = true;

        //c canvas event listners
        canvas.on("mouse:down", function (o) {
          isDown = true;
          if (mode_rect) {
            pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
            origX = pointer.x;
            origY = pointer.y;
            console.log(origX + "," + origY);
            rect = new fabric.Rect({
              left: origX,
              top: origY,
              originX: "left",
              originY: "top",
              width: pointer.x - origX,
              height: pointer.y - origY,
              fill: "red",
              angle: 0,
              fill: "rgba(255,0,0,0.0)",
              stroke: "black",
              strokeWidth: 1,
            });
            canvas.add(rect);
          }
        });

        canvas.on("mouse:move", function (o) {
          if (mode_rect) {
            if (isDown) {
              var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

              if (origX > pointer.x) {
                rect.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
              }
              if (origY > pointer.y) {
                rect.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
              }

              rect.set({ width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) });
              rect.set({ height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y) });

              canvas.renderAll();
            }
          }
        });
      }

      //c freehand drawing/Highlighter
      if (e.key == 2) {
        console.log("freehand");
        isDown = true;
        mode_free = true;
        mode_uline = false;
        mode_rect = false;
        canvas.isDrawingMode = 1;
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "rgba(255,0,0,0.2)";
        canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 20;

        //c canvas event listners
        canvas.on("mouse:down", function (o) {
          isDown = true;
          if (mode_free) {
            canvas.renderAll();
          }
        });
      }

      //c line mode
      if (e.key == 3) {
        var line;
        console.log("line");
        isDown = true;
        mode_free = false;
        mode_uline = true;
        mode_rect = false;

        //c canvas event listners
        canvas.on("mouse:down", function (o) {
          isDown = true;
          var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
          var points = [pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y];
          if (mode_uline) {
            line = new fabric.Line(points, {
              strokeWidth: 3,
              fill: "red",
              stroke: "red",
              originX: "center",
              originY: "center",
              targetFindTolerance: true,
            });
            canvas.add(line);
          }
        });
        canvas.on("mouse:move", function (o) {
          if (!isDown) return;
          var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

          if (mode_uline) {
            line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
            canvas.renderAll();
          }
        });
      }

      //c deleting a selected shape
      if (e.key == 4) {
        var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (activeObject) {
          canvas.remove(activeObject);
        }
      }

      //c cancling freehand drawing mode
      if (e.key == "x") {
        console.log("freehand mode cancled");
        canvas.isDrawingMode = 0;
      }
    });

    //c removing previous event listeners and resetting some global variables
    canvas.on("mouse:up", function (o) {
      isDown = false;
      mode_free = false;
      mode_uline = false;
      mode_rect = false;
      canvas.off("mouse:down");
      canvas.off("mouse:move");
    });
  });
}

function save_canvas() {}

function load_canvas() {}
```

**solution**

I setup a custom trigger event after the ajax call is made. When the trigger event is fired, only then I create fabricjs canvases.
(apparently even with promises, the fabric code was not running in correct order. Which was probably due to bad syntax. Custom triggers solve this issue.)

**[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zv4s.png)**

-Each image appear separately in its own fabric.js canvas as background.
-Each canvas is independent.

Answer (score 0):

Have create for you just copy code and then use your own images in local to get actual full result in output div( images will generated) .

```js
      let CANVAS_LIST = [];
        let imageList = [
            'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png',
            'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png',
            'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png',
        ]

        imageList.forEach(element => {


            let canvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvasElement.width = '300';
            canvasElement.height = '300';
            $("#canvas_container").append(canvasElement);
            let canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasElement);

            // Adding Example Text here. 
            canvas.add(new fabric.Text('This text is added', {
                fontFamily: 'Delicious_500',
                color: 'red',
                left: 10,
                top: 100
            }));
            // Setting up  Background to dynamic generated Canvas
            canvas.setBackgroundImage(
                `${element}`,
                canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
                {
                    backgroundImageOpacity: 1,
                    backgroundImageStretch: false,
                }
            );

            CANVAS_LIST.push(canvas);
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
            generateOutput();
        }, 3000);
        function generateOutput() {
            $("#output").empty();
            CANVAS_LIST.forEach(canvas => {
                let image = $("<img>").attr({
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    src: canvas.toDataURL()

                });

                image.css({ marginLeft: '20px' });

                $("#output").append(image);
            })
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {}
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.1.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="canvas_container">
        </div>
        <button onclick="generateOutput()"> Show output</button>
        <div id="output">

        </div>
    </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: hi, I'm getting "Tainted canvases may not be exported" when calling toDataUrl.
Also I would really like to know why my code is not working in the first place. updated post.

Comment: Don't use  remote Images  when working on local, in above example  there are remote URLs, Just download them in the folder and then put in single folder and  run it in localhost server.  

it will work.

Comment: doest that help you?